# Show post with an associated image

Tags: image, file-upload, axios, vuejs3, laravel-9

I am trying to display a post with a background image. The data of the post is displayed perfectly, what I can't display is the image associated to the post. The data is in one table, and the associated image in another.

This is what I have in the script:

```
data() {
    return {
      posts: [],
      //images:[],
    };
  },
  mounted() {    
    //let firstValue = "";

    axios.all([
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/facebookPosts/list'),
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/facebookImages/list')
    ])
      .then(axios.spread((facebookPosts, facebookImages) => {
        this.posts = facebookPosts.data;
        this.images = facebookImages.data;
        console.log(this.images);

        const lastObject = facebookImages.data[facebookImages.data.length - 1];
        firstValue = lastObject[Object.keys(lastObject)[1]];
        console.log(firstValue);

      }))
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
```

And this is what I have in the template:

```
<SwiperSlide v-for="post in posts" :key="post.id">
      <!--<a v-bind:href="post.url" target="_blank">-->
      <div class="text-mst_white h-[600px] md:h-[500px] xl:h-96 flex justify-center items-center">
        <img :src="image" class="
              w-full
              h-full
              object-cover
              absolute
              mix-blend-overlay
              object-left-bottom
              brightness-50
              blur-sm
              md:object-center
            " />
        <div class="text-center">
          <h1 class="text-5xl">{{ post.title }}</h1>
          <h2 class="text-xl h-7 md:pr-40 md:text-right md:text-2xl">
            {{ post.date }}
          </h2>
          <p class="
              text-base
              p-8
              tracking-wider
              leading-relaxed
              md:px-40 md:text-2xl
              flex-grow
            ">
            {{ post.content }}
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--</a>-->
    </SwiperSlide>
```

I have tried several things but there is no way.

Comment: fetching "images" is a bit ambiguous.  depending on what `facebookImages.data` actually is (URL, blob, byte array, etc.), you may need to prepare/reformat the data in some way before it can be displayed.